в hackthebox не получается отсканировать сеть машины,не видит или неправильно подключение
На сайте hackthebox выполняю первую лабу Meow , с помощью openvpn подключился сначала к machines, потом к Starting point, оба в разных окнах и не выключались, в третьем окне пытался сначала с помощью команды ping просканировать сеть машины, потом с помощью nmap просканировать порты, выдаётся ,после зашёл на сайт, увидел что в настройках virtual box должен стоять сетевой мост- поставил. ничего не изменилось. При подключение же с помощью openvpn , казалось бы ,как по инструкции выдаётся Initialization Sequence Completed, как у всех в гайдах, но у меня после этой строчки ещё идёт вот эти строчкис start point аналогично. Подскажите ,пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему или перенаправьте туда где проблема уже решена.

Попробуй сбросить текущие маршруты перед подключением к VPN, чтобы избежать конфликта:
sudo ip route flush table main
sudo ip -6 route flush table main

Мне помогло
А по 3 строчкам в конце лога, у меня также.
Последние строки лога, которые у тебя, это:
Data Channel: cipher 'AES-256-CBC', auth 'SHA256' — говорит о том, что VPN-канал шифруется с помощью алгоритма AES-256-CBC, а для аутентификации используется SHA256. Это нормальные настройки для OpenVPN.
Timers: ping 10, ping-restart 120 — эти параметры управляют таймерами. ping 10 означает, что OpenVPN клиент будет отправлять "ping" запросы каждые 10 секунд для проверки подключения. ping-restart 120 означает, что если в течение 120 секунд ответа не будет, OpenVPN попробует переподключиться.
Protocol options: explicit-exit-notify 1 — говорит клиенту уведомить сервер, если соединение закрывается, что полезно при внезапном разрыве.

у меня теперь бесконечный рестарт, а в ifconfig половина пропала
